# update of android application get crashed when download and install from google play?

Tags: android

I have app on  android google play.then with some changes i uloaded new app on google play .it get uploaded successfully with new version.but in new app data is not coming . i have sqlite database in my app .
what need to do ?

Comment: Please post the logcat trace of your app.

Comment: i cannot able to trace logcat. aap is updated from google play then data is not coming in updated app.

Comment: At my job, we recently had a kind of same issue. We struggled to find that previously submitted app' had been compiled on a Linux platform and the new one on a freaking macbook... We've absolutely no idea why it behaved like this... But maybe your problem is completly different.

Comment: You should read this article, in particular the information about version numbers and onUpgrade().  http://www.drdobbs.com/database/using-sqlite-on-android/232900584

Comment: You might want to post what worked for you, as an answer, so that others will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had make changes in database(added two columns in databse) while uploading second version of app. but I did not take care of versioning of database in new upload . Thats it was getting crashed .

If anyone have database in app please do care for each upload on google play . this link will help you to [Helpful Link for versioning app containng databse](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/using-sqlite-on-android/232900584)

thanks and regards.